# Python, Counting list objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code:

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
lines = handle.read().splitlines()
hour = []
times = []
unq = []
counts = dict()
for ln in lines:
    if 'From ' in ln :
        words = ln.split()
        times = (words[5])
        for time in times:
            split_time = times.split(':')
            hour = (split_time[0]).counts(hour + 1)
            if hour not in unq:
                unq.append(hour)
print(*unq, counts, sep = "\n")
```

I get a traceback:

> Enter file: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/gamer/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch.py",
>   line 15, in 
>       hour = (split_time[0]).counts(hour + 1) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'counts'

I'm trying to count the objects in 'hour' but I'm unsure of the correct syntax.  Any hints?

Comment: What do you expect this line to do `hour = (split_time[0]).counts(hour + 1)` ?

Comment: is split_times supposed to be a list?

Comment: Yes, that's what `str.split` produces. (Assuming you mean `split_time`, not `split_times`, which doesn't appear in the code.)

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, thanks! I wasn't sure about that. On hind sight I should probably have googled it before asking. :(